# How to pass text file contents as argument to console application?

Tags: command-line, files, console

What is the command line to run a console application with input argument fed from text file?

```
text_file:
This is a simple text file with characters and other
symbols including tabs and new lines
```

The console should get

```
$./myapp "This is a simple text file with characters and other symbols including tabs and new lines"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$()` (command substitution). With double quotes to pass all the text as a single argument:

```
./myapp "$(cat text_file)"
```

Or, using the older form with backticks `` ` ` ``:

```
./myapp "`cat text_file`"
```

You can run without quotes to have the shell split and expand (if wildcards are present) the text:

```
./myapp $(cat text_file)
./myapp `cat text_file`
```

Comment: This works too, or theres about 10,000 other ways.

Comment: many thanks, let me try them. will the contents be passed in quotes? to treat them as a single argument since there are spaces in text file

Comment: To pass all the text as single argument you should run `./myapp "$(cat text_file)"`.

Comment: yes, that is the case

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, cat it.

`cat file | some_script.sh`

Have a look [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) for further help.

Comment: This will redirect the content of file to the standard input of some_script.sh, not as command line argument.

Comment: True but the question was "with input argument fed from text file" and if some_script.sh takes stdin then the "effect" is the same without having to worry about argument length issues or escaping.